Mistake in React Native Project when yarn start
My project suddenly got an error like this
Error: Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path from /Users/gys/Documents/FEDev/Project/PupPunch/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/src/assets/back-icon-mask.png: missing-asset-registry-path could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/node_modules
  node_modules
> 1 | �PNG
  2 | 
  3 | 
  4 | IHDR2���gAMA��
                    �a cHRMz&�����u0�`:�p��Q<bKGD���̿tIME�
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/gys/Documents/FEDev/Project/PupPunch/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/gys/Documents/FEDev/Project/PupPunch/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:232:43)
    at /Users/gys/Documents/FEDev/Project/PupPunch/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:156:21
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/gys/Documents/FEDev/Project/PupPunch/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:42:25)
    at visit (/Users/gys/Documents/FEDev/Project/PupPunch/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:83:30)
    at async Promise.all (index 19)
    at async visit (/Users/gys/Documents/FEDev/Project/PupPunch/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async visit (/Users/gys/Documents/FEDev/Project/PupPunch/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 6)

When I try to modify the metro.config.ts like the other 's post, but it doesn't, I have tried the method like update the dependency
this is my metro.config.js
const path = require('path');
const {getDefaultConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');

module.exports = {
  ...getDefaultConfig(__dirname),
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: getDefaultConfig(__dirname).resolver.assetExts.filter(
      ext => ext !== 'svg',
    ),
    sourceExts: [...getDefaultConfig(__dirname).resolver.sourceExts, 'svg'],
    resolverMainFields: ['sbmodern', 'react-native', 'browser', 'main'],
  },
  watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../')],
};


other methods such as clean the cache and restart,(npx react-native start --reset-cache), update the dependency(yarn add @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/elements、 rm -rf node_modules yarn install) has been tried and they don't work, either!
